# Setting message Id using smtp may be reset after that?

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient, pop3

I have client that send emails using the smtp protocol but I need to save message Id for each email I sent , I searched a lot about get message Id but i didn't find way so I have to set it by my self in code .
My question is does mail server guarantees that the message id that I set the header will not be replaced or reset by the mail server after sending email?

I tried my code and it's working when I send email to Gmail and after email sent still keep message id set by me.
but I'm not sure if it working always with all emails ?

the reason to set message id cuz I need to save this message id in data base cuz after that i'll retrieve replies for each sent email  and I found the only way to correlate this email with its replies is the message id.

thanks in advance and I wish to find reply here

```
 Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();  
 mail.Headers.Add("Message-Id", String.Format("<{0}@{1}>", id.tostring(), "mail.example.com"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "guarantee" per se, but it's rare that an SMTP (or other) mail server will replace your `Message-ID` header.

That said, while using a Guid technically works, it *is* a really really long string for use as a `Message-ID`. Here's how I generate a `Message-Id` in [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit):

```
const string base36 = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

static void GetRandomBytes (byte[] buffer)
{
    using (var random = RandomNumberGenerator.Create ())
        random.GetBytes (buffer);
}

/// <summary>
/// Generates a Message-Id.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Generates a new Message-Id using the supplied domain.
/// </remarks>
/// <returns>The message identifier.</returns>
/// <param name="domain">A domain to use.</param>
/// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">
/// <paramref name="domain"/> is <c>null</c>.
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">
/// <paramref name="domain"/> is invalid.
/// </exception>
public static string GenerateMessageId (string domain)
{
    if (domain == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (domain));

    if (domain.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException ("The domain is invalid.", nameof (domain));

    ulong value = (ulong) DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    var id = new StringBuilder ();
    var block = new byte[8];

    GetRandomBytes (block);

    do {
        id.Append (base36[(int) (value % 36)]);
        value /= 36;
    } while (value != 0);

    id.Append ('.');

    value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        value = (value << 8) | (ulong) block[i];

    do {
        id.Append (base36[(int) (value % 36)]);
        value /= 36;
    } while (value != 0);

    id.Append ('@').Append (domain);

    return id.ToString ();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jstedfast for reply , I used GUID to make sure this ID will never ever be repeated , but there is any problem to use long message ID?? specially if i didn't set it by default message id will be set with long id

Comment: Well, header lines are meant to fit within 78 characters, so ideally a Message-Id would fit within that (including the "Message-ID: " string). My solution above is also going to produce a unique string and is the recommended (from the specs) way of doing it.

Comment: A Guid *will* work just fine, though, if that's what you'd prefer to do.